# OpenMP - parallelize a loop

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I have been trying to parallelize with this loop with OpenMP

```
#define AX(i,j,k) (Ax[((k)*n+(j))*n+(i)])
for (int k = k1; k < k2; ++k) {
    for (int j = j1; j < j2; ++j) {
        for (int i = i1; i < i2; ++i) {
            double xx = AX(i,j,k);
            double xn = (i > 0)   ? AX(i-1,j,k) : 0;
            double xe = (j > 0)   ? AX(i,j-1,k) : 0;
            double xu = (k > 0)   ? AX(i,j,k-1) : 0;
            AX(i,j,k) = (xx+xn+xe+xu)/6*w;
        }
    }
}
#undef AX
```

I put this at the top of this code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private (k,j,i) shared(Ax)
```

I noticed, however, that the `#pragma` is not working, since my function is simultaneously faster but generates more inconsistent results (probably due to data dependencies).

I probably have to put another clause or try to change something in the code, but I don't have any idea as to what.

EDIT :

Okay thank you I understand why it is not working but I tried why you said, and unfortunetaly it is still  not working. Yet, I know the problem but I don't know how to solve it.

```
void ssor_forward_sweep(int n, int i1, int i2, int j1, int j2, int k1, int k2, 
                    double* restrict Ax, double w)
{

int k,j,i;

double* AxL=malloc(n*sizeof(double));
for (int a=0; a < n;a++){
AxL[a]=Ax[a];
}
#define AX(i,j,k) (Ax[((k)*n+(j))*n+(i)])
#define AXL(i,j,k) (AxL[((k)*n+(j))*n+(i)])

#pragma omp parallel for private (k,j,i) shared(Ax)
for (k = k1; k < k2; ++k) {
    for (j = j1; j < j2; ++j) {     
        for (i = i1; i < i2; ++i) {

            double xx = AXL(i,j,k);
            double xn = (i > 0)   ? AXL(i-1,j,k) : 0;
            double xe = (j > 0)   ? AXL(i,j-1,k) : 0;
            double xu = (k > 0)   ? AXL(i,j,k-1) : 0;
            AX(i,j,k) = (xx+xn+xe+xu)/6*w;
            //AXL(i,j,k) = (xx+xn+xe+xu)/6*w;
        }
    }
}
#undef AX
#undef AXL
```

I know that there is still a problem with data dependencies but I don't know how to solve it ; indeed modified values aren't taking in account for the new ones. It also may have a problem when I am copying data.
When I am saying it is not working I don't have any output (no error and no output), it is just directly crashing.

Hope someone can help me !

Thank you so much for the help !
Best regards,

Comment: What do you mean by _it is not working_? Does it error? Does it run slow? Does it give the wrong result? Please, be specific in you answer (**do not answer to this comment, but edit the question**).

Comment: Furthermore, please, provide a minimal working example that we can test; the code you have posted, by it self, cannot be compiled/executed.

Comment: It's not working because the there is no coordination of the threads reading and writing elements of `AX`.  For example, the update to `AX(3,4,5)` depends on the values of `AX(2,4,5), AX(3,3,5), AX(3,4,4)` which may be updated by other threads in a sequence which is different from the sequence of updates in the sequential code.  There is an easy fix, make 2 arrays, `AX_old` and `AX_new`, and update from old to new, then shuffle a couple of pointers around.  But this costs memory.

Comment: Thank you, I edit my post with new problem that I met and try to modify and add informations !

Comment: Sorry I didn't put the function. I put shared AxL and it's still giving nothing as output.